# Как элегантно заменить в Python-строке 8 на +7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан номер мобильного, скажем `'8-912-888-99-99'`. Как заменить восьмерку в начале этой строки на +7?

Очевидно, что метод `replace()` не подходит.
Использование `re` я нахожу избыточным и не красивым для столь "простой" задачи.

Неужто ничего нельзя сделать?

Comment: `'+7' + '8-912-888-99-99'[1:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@S.Nick:

> `'+7' + '8-912-888-99-99'[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

```
'8-912-888-99-99'.replace('8', '+7', 1)
```

**Результат**

```
'+7-912-888-99-99'
```

Метод `replace()` имеет опциональный аргумент `count` - заменить только первые `count` вхождений.